# How to get value from one component to the other in react js?

Tags: java, reactjs

I tried to get value from other component with the help of props, but it’s not working.

Here is my logic

main.js makes request to child.js component and in child.js I get age but it isn’t working.

```
class Main Connect extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
       this.age = this.props.age
   }

   render() {
      <Child />
      return(this.age)
   }

}

class Child Connect extends Component {

   render()
      return(<Main age='21' />)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Both of your components are looking wrong and many corrections required

Your code

```
    //don’t what is Connect here. A class followed its class name must be single word
     class Main Connect extends Component {
           constructor(props) {
               //you need to call super(props); here to get props from parent inside constructor 
               // set age to a state but what you are doing below isn’t right way
               this.age = this.props.age
            }

          render() {
              // this is totally wrong check my corrected code below to understand better
             <Child />
                 return(this.age)
              }

         }

        class Child Connect extends Component {

               render()
                  return(<Main age='21' />)

         }
```

Check below updated code. This is how it works from parent to child

```
   class Main extends Component{
       render() {
          return (<div><Child age='21' /></div>)
       }
    }

   class Child extends Component {
       constructor(props){
           super(props);
           this.state = {
               age: props.age
           }
       }
       render(){
           return(<div><h1>{this.state.age}</h1></div>)
       }
```

PS:- you got negative votes from others because the sentences are incorrect and you posted incomplete which has lot of issues.

Comment: No need to save `age` to state. Just `<h1>{this.props.age}</h1>`

Comment: Yes agreed. I added that to the state because Denies Azi specifically mentioned that he is not getting props.age in constructor so to mak him understand I added to the state in constructor

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is your scenario. An input element's change is a typical case to pass props upwards. For this use function via properties to handle change (and also pass the actual value back to the input):

**Main.js**

```
import AgeInput from './AgeInput';

class Main extends Component {
  state = {
    age: ''
  }

  handleAgeInputChange = ({target}) => {
    const { value: age } = target;
    this.setState({ age })
  }

  render() {
    return <AgeInput onChange={this.handleAgeInputChange} value={this.state.age} />
  }
}
```

**AgeInput.js** (Child)

```
const AgeInput = ({ onChange, value }) => (
  <input onChange={onChange} value={value} />
);

export default AgeInput;
```